# Creating weak_ptr<> from raw pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, weak-ptr

I'd like to wrap raw pointer member to some smart pointer to prevent deleting inside a developing class. Owner of the object under pointer is outside of class. So, looks like `boost::shared_ptr` and `std::auto_ptr` does not fit. The following is a reduced example:

```
class Foo {
  boost::weak_ptr<Bar> m_bar;
public:
  void setBar(const Bar *bar) { // bar created on heap
    m_bar = bar;                // naturally compilation error
  }
};
```

Of course, it induces compilation error. What is a correct way to initialize `weak_ptr` from a raw pointer (if exist)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [shared\_ptr & weak\_ptr conversions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522020/shared-ptr-weak-ptr-conversions)

Comment: If you want to prevent deletion of that pointer within your class then don't call `delete` on it, and don't provide accessor functions that expose the pointer to clients. `weak_ptr` is meant for non-owning view of an object owned by a `shared_ptr`. If you were able to somehow stuff that pointer into a `weak_ptr` it'd have no idea whether the pointer has expired, nor does it prevent me from calling `delete m_bar.lock().get();` within your class. You can never make everything 100% idiot-proof.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't do that, you can only create a weak_ptr out of a shared_ptr or another weak_ptr.
So the idea would be that the owner of the pointer hold a shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer, and everything should be ok.

Answer (score 11):

The only way to do it is by getting hold of a `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` that owns the pointer, otherwise the `weak_ptr` has no way to find the existing owner in order to share ownership with it.

The only way to get a `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer that is already owned by another `shared_ptr` is if `Bar` derives from `enable_shared_from_this<Bar>`, then you can do

```
m_bar = bar->shared_from_this();
```

Answer (score 8):

The purpose of a weak pointer is to be unable to use the raw pointer if it had been deleted. However, if you have a raw pointer, the weak pointer has no way to know that it was deleted. Instead, you must have a shared_ptr somewhere which "owns" the raw pointer. Then you can create a weak_ptr which references the shared_ptr.

When the shared_ptr goes out of scope and is the last "strong" smart pointer, it will automatically delete the raw pointer. Then, when you try to lock the weak_ptr, it will see that there is no "strong" pointer remaining and therefore the object does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you've said seems perfectly reasonable, except for one thing:

```
void setBar(const Bar *bar)
```

This shouldn't take a raw pointer.  It should take a `weak_ptr` ideally, or possibly a `shared_ptr` if you have some compelling argument.

The actual owner of the object in question should construct the `weak_ptr` and than call `setBar` with that.  This preserves the ownership semantics.  It looks like what you're doing is having the owning object take a raw pointer and pass that to `setBar`.  This creates a semantic gap in the ownership of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Pass shared pointer instead of raw pointer, and create your weak pointer from that shared pointer. This is really the only way if owner of the pointer is outside of a class.